# windowspe - find devices whitout proper driver

Tags: portable-executable, findstr, winpe

I'm trying to automate the installation of drivers with windows PE.
After booting PE and looking for the devices I get such an output:

```
devcon status *pci*
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0C05&SUBSYS_11F41734&REV_06\3&11583659&0&09
    Name: PCI standard PCI-to-PCI bridge
    Driver is running.
PCI\VEN_19A2&DEV_0800&SUBSYS_11CC1734&REV_00\4&313340F4&0&01E0
    Name: Coprocessor
    The device has the following problem: 28
```

Now, I'm only interested in the devices with an error/problem.

How can I figure out which devices are affected?

I tried it with findstr:

```
devcon status *pci* | findstr /n /i "pci\\ name problem"
```

But i always get all devices, not only the faulty ones.

The easiest way seems to use a file

```
devcon status *pci* > devcon.txt
findstr /n /i "problem" devcon.txt
```

with this I get the line numbers.
But how can I read now the line 2 lines above the line containing "problem"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, after one day of research i can answer myself my question ;)

the easyiest way to solve this problem is linux grep (from cygwin64)

i´ve installed cygwin and copied this files to pe

- grep.exe
- cygiconv-2.dll
- cygintl-8.dll
- cygpcre-1.dll
- cygwin1.dll

my commandline looks now like this

**devcon status *pci * | grep -B2 -i -e problem -e stopped** *> errors.txt*

probably i can shorten this command, but i´m happy thats working.

netlord